# Inheritance of a class that also inherits the same base class as this class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

One of the advantages of inheritance for me is that public methods are written once in the base class, and each inheriting class automatically has that method also.

Now for example lets say I want to provide each class in my software with a 'swap' method. The class that provides this functionality looks like:

```
template< typename... DataMembers > 
class SwapMethodProvider
{
public:

    inline void Swap( SwapMethodProvider& other );

private:

    std::tuple< DataMembers... > member_dataMembers;

};

template< typename... DataMembers >
inline void SwapMethodProvider< DataMembers... >::Swap( SwapMethodProvider& other )
{
    // Swap between the tuples that contain the data members
    std::swap( member_dataMembers, other.member_dataMembers );
}
```

Now, if only one class inherits from this every thing is good. But if I want every class in my software to inherit from this then the following won't work because the direct base class is inaccessible due to ambiguity:

```
class ExtraSauce : public SwapMethodProvider< int, double >
{};

class EvenMoreExtraSauce : public ExtraSauce, public SwapMethodProvider< int, double >
{};
```

Then the first class 'ExtraSauce' will work fine, but 'EvenMoreExtraSauce' will not compile. Now I understand why it does not compile, but what is left to do is to store the 'SwapMethodProvider' instance of the class as a data member. My problem is just with repeating code, because each class will need to have its own 'Swap' method that calls the 'Swap' method of the 'SwapMethodProvider' instance.

First of all, am I right so far? I will like to know for sure that this behavior is not possible.

Second of all, why is inheritance so badly supported behind one level? It is so cool to write a method once and then let all the objects inherit from it. Even if the same object appears more then once in a class in various ways.

Comment: it is not really the case that inheritance is badly supported but inheritance itself gets nasty at some point. Consider that inheritance is not the holy grail and maybe take a look at [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), in fact no inheritance at all is needed to swap arbitrary types

Comment: Assuming it compiles. When you call Swap on your EvenMoreExtraSauce which behavior do you expect?

Comment: Something like the behavior of the constructor, that there can be special method that calls the same method for all the base classes

Comment: [It compiles jolly well](https://ideone.com/QsQO5w). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: If you have not defined a Swap method in your EvenMoreExtraSauce  that calls ExtraSauce::Swap then/or SwapMethodProvider< std::string >::Swap. How the compiler shall analyse EvenMoreExtraSauce ::Swap ? is it  ExtraSauce::Swap or SwapMethodProvider< std::string >::Swap. In constructor, by default it will call the default constructor for each class but for method it can't choose an arbitrary option.

Comment: Sorry, the 2 'SwapMethodProvider' had different template arguments, therefore they were different classes. I fixed it. Because 'EvenMoreExtraSauce' inherits from all, all the swap methods of the base class can be just called with 'this' pointer. What you said is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRTP.

```
template <class Parent, typename... DataMembers> 
class SwapMethodProvider { ... };
class ExtraSauce : public SwapMethodProvider <ExtraSauce, int, double> {};
class EvenMoreExtraSauce : public ExtraSauce, 
                           public SwapMethodProvider<EvenMoreExtraSauce, int, double> {};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It was fun passing this with some help